# Alarm Manager not invoking correctly

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

I am invoking Broadcast at the alarm time which internally invoking the service.

I am using following code for invoking the data `Alarm` from `AlarmManager`

```
public void startAlert(Timestamp timestamp, int id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BroadCastMessage.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("id", id);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp.getTime());

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

I have printing Calendar object. Data in this object is correct.

But this broadcast event is getting fired at the time of I am creating alarm instead of the time at which I am setting the alarm

I have gone through some links which are talking about the accuracy of alarm or alarm not invoking timely or `exact/Inexact`. But none of these suits here because it is invoking at the time of setting alarm.

What could be reason?

Comment: What is the date printed? And what is the value of timestamp.getTime()?

Comment: If your alarm fires directly, then the timestamp is in the past. Your timestamp is wrong, you should show how you build it. Also, setExact() not working since API19, since this API all alarms fire inexact. So why do you set `setExact()` on all API >= 19 ?

Comment: this is the date object that is printing:  `java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1493224080000,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=Asia/Calcutta,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2017,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=17,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=26,DAY_OF_YEAR=116,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=21,MINUTE=58,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]`

Comment: @Opiatefuchs any thing else is required for analyse ?